# HDMI connected Samsung Monitor says "Not Optimum Mode, Recommended Mode 1920x1080 60 hz"

Tags: display

Every time the monitor goes to sleep (10minutes setting in OS) and during the boot I have a notification in the middle of the screen with the error message I wrote in the title. I can understand that during reboot the resolution isn't optimal, but how come the monitor think's the resolution is wrong when the OS shuts down the displays due inactivity? It's pretty darn annoying!

Does anyone know any tricks to get rid of the popup? Btw, I don't get the message with a DVI cable, but with my current 3 monitor setup I need to have said monitor connected with an HDMI cable as it's the only one of my three that has it, and there are only two DVI connectors in my GPU.

Comment: If no one else has a good solution, you might just get an HDMI to DVI converter or cable.

Comment: Apparently your computer and your monitor don't communicate the [ACPI settings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) the right way over the HDMI cable. You can try to put your monitor asleep before your computer shuts the screen down. It's probably in the menu of your monitor somewhere (don't know your monitor type, so can't help you any further on that aspect).

Comment: I also get this with my new Samsung UHD S732 4K monitor going through a KVM. The KVM doesn't support 4K60, and I don't use 4K on any of the devices on that monitor. So every time I switch inputs or resolutions, the monitor complains about the input not being 4K60. For people leaving answers: this is not a Windows problem (this isn't even on a PC), so changing resolution in Windows is not the answer (and not possible.)

Answer (score 1):

I have 5 Syncmaster monitors and I have found this issue very troubling with 3 out of 5. I found some partial solutions and or workarounds. The workaround solution of hitting the Menu or OCR button on the side or bottom right of the monitor for an instant, shuts the Optimum Resolution message off until the next time you turn it on. This is an issue with all the Syncmaster models newer than b2030.

Syncmaster 2033 has the problem when using a DVI to VGA adapter on the PC and a VGA cable from adapter to monitor, occurring every time you turn monitor on or bring it out of sleep regardless of what the resolution is set at. With a DVI to DVI or VGA to VGA it only reports Optimum Resolution notice if you exceed the optimum resolution. The OS, GPU, or HDMI cable are not related to this, except for the HDMI cable which must be a special high speed designation for 4K display or will not do 2160p.

Syncmaster b2030 only displays optimum resolution notice if you exceed the optimum resolution. This model works with all connector configurations, IE: DVI to DVI, VGA to VGA, HDMI to HDMI, And DVI to VGA Adapter and VGA from adapter to monitor.

Syncmaster B1940 never displays the optimal resolution notice including when you exceed the max resolution of both the monitor and GPU by creating a custom resolution. I tried all the way to 1920 by 1080 successfully without Optimum resolution notice (monitor and GPU only can go to 1280 x 1024 max).

I did notice variations in my DVI cables, even though they all had the same logo markings. One DVI had 3 rows of pins and a flat blade pin on one side. The second DVI cable had 2 sets of 3 rows with the middle 2 columns of pins missing and a flat blade pin on one side. The third DVI cable had 3 rows of pins with a flat blade pin on one side with 4 pins boxing in the flat blade pin. The fourth DVI connector was an antique with 4 rows of pins and no flat blade connector. Additionally, I seem to remember a DVI connector I had with 3 rows of pins and 2 flat blade pins at 90 degrees from each other.

The problem seems to be due to how different Syncmaster monitors handle the slightly modified communication due to use of DVI to VGA adapter.

Specifically, My DVI to VGA adapter has the 3 rows of pins with the one side blade pin boxed in by 4 pins. The DVI to DVI cables I have, are missing either the 4 pins that box the blade pin or they are missing the center 2 columns of pins and the 4 pins that box the blade pin.

I tested the theory of a possible fix, that would only be available to a PC with a GPU control app like NVIDIA Control Panel or AMD Radeon software that allows creation of custom resolutions and especially Option to change scaling from application to GPU usually under the HDMI or Flat monitor options.

Using AMD Radeon software I went into Home then select the settings gear icon and then select display and then disable GPU scaling. When I have GPU scaling on I get the Optimal Resolution notice right away and again every time I start the monitor or come out of sleep even if the resolution is correct. When I have GPU scaling off I only get the Optimal Resolution notice if I exceed the optimal resolution.

Using Nvidia Control Panel You go to display and then set display size and position and then select Use the following settings select scaling and then select none for scaling mode and select desktop for scaling to stop the optimal resolution notice.

Comment: If a question is five minutes old (or even five hours), there’s some benefit to posting a partial answer quickly and then coming back to improve it.   But, when a question is over five *years* old, it probably makes sense to do enough experimentation to be able to post an actual solution that you know to work (even if only for you) rather than hinting at a theoretical possible fix.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using dual monitor on the non-Samsung computer: Display => choose Samsung monitor => Display adapter properties => List All Modes => choose the right resolution and Hertz that's the same as the recommended mode of the Samsung computer.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the MENU button and scroll down to the second from the bottom with the name SYSTEM. Hit SOURCE to select it, the hit the down button until the options become AV mode and HDMI Black Level. Go to AV mode and hit Source to select it. Now press up or down to change the setting to OFF. Exit the menu. As long as AV mode is off, the monitor will display perfectly. If the color looks strange, change HDMI Black Level to Normal instead of the default LOW as well.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Todayboy worked for me, however need to know that the issue was solved by switching to any resolution of **60HZ frequency**, eventhough the message on the screen was asking for 1920x1080 which has no 60Hz resolution.
SO >
Advanced display settings>display adapter properties for Display2>"popup window" List All Models>1680x1050 60Hertz

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this problem in my way.

- Open Display Setting Panel
- Select your display
- Select the recommended resolution
- plug out and again plug in the display cable

Its works for me. Try this out I think it will work for all 100%.

Comment: The error is coming from the monitor, not Windows. And if you use any resolution other than the monitor's maximum, the monitor complains.

Answer (score -3):

Right click in the main window -> Select `Graphics Options` -> Select `Balloon Notification` -> Select `Optimal Resolution Notification` -> `Disable`

Comment: It's a notification in the monitor, not in the OS. Thanks still.

Comment: The instruction was for the monitor but may not work for all. A cheap and cheerful but irritating option is to press the menu button (top one on the right of the monitor) and the message goes away immediately. If you're using a VGA cable consider upgrading to a DVI or HDMI to DVI cable

Comment: HDMI cable is the source of the issue. I've sorted the problem out with a converter.

Comment: I wonder how somebody "right clicks" if the instructions are for the monitor...

Comment: This looks like steps for Windows, not for the display. The problem is Samsung displays try to "mansplain" when you're not running optimal resolution. I may "solve" this issue by returning the monitor and getting another brand.